# How do I get the current users Availability (Available, Off-Work, Away...) in MS Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams, skypedeveloper

I have a service that works with Skype to report on a users (LyncClient.Self.Contact) availabiliy. How do I get this from MS Teams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not yet available. We do have plans to add this to Microsoft Graph but we do not have an ETA.